# Не получается открыть базу данных

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

При попытке открыть БД следующим кодом вылетает ошибка.

```
string connect = @"Data Source = "+databaseName+";Initial Catalog = " + databaseName +"; Integrated Security = True";

 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
```

и таким кодом тоже:

```
string sConnectionString;
sConnectionString = "Password=myPassword;User ID=myUserID;"
                   + "Initial Catalog=pubs;"
                    + "Data Source=databaseName";
SqlConnection objConn
= new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
objConn.Open();
```

B при попытке открыть БД через OleDbConnection.

Текст исключения:

> Необработанное исключение типа
>   "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: При установлении соединения с SQL Server
>   произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром.
>   Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано
>   правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения.
>   (provider: Сетевые интерфейсы SQL, error: 26 - Ошибка при обнаружении
>   указанного сервера или экземпляра)

Comment: myUserId, databaseName - Ваши реальные данные ?

Comment: Вы подключаетесь к локальной базе? У вас стоит SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: А какая у вас БД? Что-то не понял, при чём тут OleDbConnection

Comment: Может у вас служба sql не запущена? Или же sql server не настроен на поддержку удаленных подключений. http://yolper.ru/12

Answer (score 2):

1. Создайте пустой .txt документ.
2. Поменяйте расширение на .udl
3. Откройте его и настройте подключения на ваш сервер.
4. Кнопкой "Проверка соединения" убедитесь что всё работает.
5. Откройте этот документ снова блокнотом(правой кнопкой мыши и изменить)
6. Скопируйте от туда строку подключения.

Answer (score 1):

`@"Data Source = " + databaseName + "` — в `databaseName` должен быть источник SqlServer.

Comment: С sql знаком очень слабо, не могли бы сказать что значит источник SqlServer?

Comment: обычно ip адрес компьютера на котором установлен неименованній екземпляр склсервера

Answer (score 0):

Data Source - это имя сервера к которому вы хотите подключиться. Впишите там имя сервера, или `.`, если подключаетесь к локальной машине.

Comment: Сделал, всё по прежнему.

Comment: @Dagger так впишите в вопрос новый код, где у вас уже имя сервера подставлено. И убедитесь что такой сервер есть и что к нему разрешены удаленные подключения.